# Menu to overlap content

Tags: css, menu

I desperately want this menu to sit at the top/on top of the content.

It's fixed, uses anchor to skip down the page... and uses some js for the smooth scrolling

I cannot get it to sit on the content like this example http://www.catscarf.com/

I've tried playing with all margin-tops but they just make it bump down the menu...or it's overlapping with something I can't find.

Can anyone help? I'm going bonkers!

http://veterinarymarketingsolutions.ca/VMSsite1/

Comment: take a deep breath, get out and get some fresh air, then come back and explain your question with more technical details if you need an accurate technical answer...what's "the menu"? There's a `header`, `nav` and `div` tag there with a few css class dynamically set.

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 2):

Simple CSS only, you need to set position to fixed, so... (using header but whatever selector you use, swap it in)

```
header{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0; /* left & right as "0" will make it full width. */
  right:0;
  z-index:99; /* z-index will place it above any element with a z-index of 98 or below */
  height: 5rem;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to be so late reading your response. Life happened. I'm going to try this, thanks SO much!! @DanWhite and Leo.

Comment: No worries @MaryFrancisWhiteman, hope it works out! Let me know how you get on...